# sending a wave file to a web service in objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services

I would like to capture a voice file in .wav format with iphone and send this .wav file to a web service. As i searched through the internet I saw that this must be done in objective C language. Since I am an absolute beginner with objective C i would appreciate if you could suggest me any ideas, approaches about how this could be performed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010343/how-do-i-record-audio-on-iphone-with-avaudiorecorder)  on Stack Overflow regarding the recording part. For creating a WAV file from your recorded audio, you could use [libsndfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939268/can-the-libsndfile-library-be-used-on-the-iphone-ios) if you are comfortable releasing your app as LGPL, although you could probably handle writing the conversion from a raw byte stream to a WAV file yourself. [It's not a complicated format](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/) if you skip the compression. You basically need to prepend a header that wouldn't change much from file to file.